# How to get the length of a string containing character references while counting the character references as one single character?

Tags: php, string, character-reference

How can I get the length of string that also contains character references? I want to count only the number of characters which will be displayed in the browser. Like

```
$raw = "Stack&#00f9"    =  Length = 6  
$raw = "Stack12345"  = Length = 10  
$raw = "Stack&#00f9&#00f9" = Length = 7
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with:

```
$len = mb_strlen(html_entities_decode($myString, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),'UTF-8');
```

Although I would first question why you have HTML entities inside your strings, as opposed to manipulating actual UTF-8 encoded strings.

Also, be careful in that your HTML entities are not correctly written (they need to end with a semicolon). If you do not add the semicolon, any entity-related functions will fail, and many browsers will fail to render your entities correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As your strings contain literal encodings of unicode chars (rather than being, say, UTF-8 encoded) you could obtain the length by simply replacing them with a dummy char, thus:

```
$length=strlen(preg_replace('/&#[0-9a-f]{4}/', '_', $raw));
```

If they *were* encoded with something PHP understands, like UTF-8, you could use [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) intead.

Comment: Due to Unicode normalization, this may erroneously report the length of `&#101&#769` as being 2, when it should only be 1 (the letter `é`).

Comment: The exact specification of the encoding he used isn't specified, but the regex could be loosened, an exercise for the reader and all that :) I'll guess the OP intended html style entities, in which case Gumbo's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

[`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) is a single-byte string function that fails on mutli-byte strings as it only returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters (since in single-byte strings every byte represents one character).

For multi-byte strings use `strlen`’s multi-byte counterpart [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) instead and don’t forget to specify the proper character encoding.

And to have HTML character references being interpreted as a single character, use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) to replace them by the characters they represent:

```
$str = html_entity_decode('Stack&#x00f9;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
var_dump(mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8'));  // int(6)
```

Note that `&#00f9` is not a valid character reference as it’s missing a `x` or `X` after `&#` for the hexadecimal notation and a `;` after the hexadecimal value.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [mb_strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
mb_strlen('string' , 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: His strings aren't UTF-8, they literally contain &#00f9

Comment: @Paul Dixon -- the question has been edited. It didn't contain entities when the question was originally asked; the entities have been edited in, and I don't believe they are what the questioner intended.  (I presume it was you that downvoted all the mb_strlen() answers?)